# MERGE with UPSERT, not inserting any value in table

Tags: sql-server, merge, upsert

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LockOfferByOfferUses](
[OfferID] [int] NULL,
[OfferCode] [varchar](50) NULL,
[LockCounter] [int] NULL,
[UpdatedDate] [datetime] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

SQL statemnt:

```
merge into LockOfferByOfferUses as Target
using (Select * from LockOfferByOfferUses Where OfferID=123 And OfferCode='abc' ) as Source
on Target.OfferID = Source.OfferID
when NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (OfferID,OfferCode,LockCounter,UpdatedDate) VALUES (123,'abc',1,GETDATE())
when MATCHED then 
update set Target.LockCounter=Target.LockCounter+1;
```

What i m trying to do is, check if a record exists in "LockOfferByOfferUse" by the offerID. If it doesn't exist, insert a record; If exists update "LockCounter" column.

The update part works, but the insertion isn't working. It's displaying message "(0 row(s) affected)". No error message.

Would really appreciate some help.

Comment: may be there are no rows matching with this clause `Select * from LockOfferByOfferUses Where OfferID=123 And OfferCode='abc'`

Comment: Without looking at the data it is hard to tell. Query looks fine

Comment: @TheGameiswar, yes there is no data. so that is the reason?

Comment: @Prdp there is no data, the table is completely empty.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The source should be the data you want to use - not another query against the target table.

So it should be something like:

```
merge into LockOfferByOfferUses as Target
using (VALUES(123)) as Source (OfferID)
on Target.OfferID = Source.OfferID
when NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (OfferID,OfferCode,LockCounter,UpdatedDate) VALUES (Source.OfferID,'abc',1,GETDATE())
when MATCHED then 
update set Target.LockCounter=Target.LockCounter+1;
```

(It's up to you where you move the other values up into the `Source` also, or just have them as literals in the `INSERT` - for more complex queries, more of the values might also be required in multiple places).

Answer (score 2):

Let's comment your query to understand what's going on:

Merge into LockOfferByOfferUses as target

```
merge into LockOfferByOfferUses as Target
```

Source query data, filter only the offerId=123

```
using (Select * from LockOfferByOfferUses Where OfferID=123 And OfferCode='abc' ) as Source
```

Condition to do the merge

```
on Target.OfferID = Source.OfferID
```

when we have a row with and Id that doesn't exist in the target we insert new data

```
when NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (OfferID,OfferCode,LockCounter,UpdatedDate) VALUES (123,'abc',1,GETDATE())
```

If we have matching data we update

```
when MATCHED then 
update set Target.LockCounter=Target.LockCounter+1;
```

Therefore what's going on is that all the Id's from your Source table exist in your target table, no need to insert new rows, the culprit is this:

> OfferID=123

You are always querying the same value, so I assume that you have the item with OfferId 123 in the target.

Corrected query:

```
merge into LockOfferByOfferUses as Target
using (Select * from LockOfferByOfferUses Where OfferCode='abc' ) as Source
on Target.OfferID = Source.OfferID
when NOT MATCHED then
INSERT (OfferID,OfferCode,LockCounter,UpdatedDate) VALUES (123,'abc',1,GETDATE())
when MATCHED then 
update set Target.LockCounter=Target.LockCounter+1;
```

With this query you would merge all the elements with OfferCode abc that do not exits yet in the target table.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation , really helped me to understand the situation :)

Answer (score 1):

Since your "Source" table is empty, there is nothing to match the target to and therefore nothing will be inserted. If you want to insert data, the source table has to contain the rows to be inserted.

**UPDATE:** Regarding your comment: Actually there are two different `WHEN NOT MATCHED` clauses: `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` and `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE`. But you can only insert values for the `WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET` clause (which seems to be the default one). But since you do not have any source data, there is nothing to insert.

Comment: OK, i thought if the ON clause doesn't match, it should just insert the values. Looks like i m wrong.